# How to access the Canopy terminal from the command line interface?

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

Lets say I wanted to add an external package to my python installation. If Canopy doesn't have it then you have to open up the GUI click tools and open the Canopy terminal and run `pip install package` which is fine and easy unless you don't have a graphical desktop installed or you are using ssh.

How do I: a) open the the Canopy Terminal tool and/or b) install external packages using only the system command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the Canopy User Python environment at the head of your PATH. See this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: Ok, the tutorials say to open the terminal through tools menu and the prompt is different so I was thinking that it was somehow different.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The Tools menu is the easiest way for most users but by no means the only way.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use GUI you can see here useful [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjY1cODOq9Q). For example, in ubuntu:
[image]

In the case when you want to use canopy without GUI, you need to activate your virtual environment using source: `~/my_venv/bin/activate`. More about you can find [here](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html).